# How to display data from a SQLite database into a GTK TreeView?

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, glade

I hope that you are doing well .

As mentioned in the title my question is : How to display data from a SQLite database into a GTK+ 3.0 TreeView using C language ?

I have two problems to do that :

1)How to correctly design the TreeView using Glade 3 to let it look like a table ?

2)How to display data received from an SQLite into that TreeView .

Thank you in advance .

Comment: Did you try anything? Is there some code? Regarding SQLite, you plan on using sqlite3 api or libgda? Also, Glade 3 has a problem setting up the cell renderers so you won't be able to do everything , ui wise, inside Glade.

Comment: I'm using sqlit3 library , 

For now , the connection to the sqlite database is fine , i 'm also able to get the result of the sql query . Codes are working perfectly .

It seems like my real  problem now is how to manipulate GtkTreeView , it is a little bit tricky .

Comment: Can you post some code? GtkTreeview follows the MVC pattern (Model - View - Controller). So you have to create a model with your data (result from the SQL query) and when setting the view (GtkTreeView) you map the TreeViewColumns to the corresponding column in the model (TreeModel - ListStore / TreeStore).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the absence of code, i 'll show a small example with dummy data:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int callback(void *, int, char **, char **);


enum {
  LIST_ID,
  LIST_BRAND,
  LIST_PRICE,
  N_COLUMNS
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   GtkCellRenderer *renderer;
   GtkTreeViewColumn *column;
   GtkListStore *store; 
   GtkWidget *window;
   GtkWidget *list;

   GtkWidget *vbox;
   GtkWidget *label;
   GtkTreeSelection *selection;

   gtk_init(&argc, &argv);


   // THIS IS THE MODEL: 3 Columns of Type String

   store = gtk_list_store_new(N_COLUMNS, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING);

   // CREATE A SQLITE FILE WITH TABLE CARS AND POPULATE WITH DATA

   sqlite3 *db;
   char *err_msg = 0;

   int rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {

       fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", 
               sqlite3_errmsg(db));
       sqlite3_close(db);

       return 1;
   }

   char *sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cars;" 
                "CREATE TABLE Cars(Id INT, Name TEXT, Price INT);" 
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(1, 'Audi', 52642);" 
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(2, 'Mercedes', 57127);" 
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(3, 'Skoda', 9000);" 
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(4, 'Volvo', 29000);" 
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(5, 'Bentley', 350000);" 
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(6, 'Citroen', 21000);" 
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(7, 'Hummer', 41400);" 
                "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(8, 'Volkswagen', 21600);";

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &err_msg);

   sql = "SELECT * FROM Cars";

   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, store, &err_msg);

   if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) {

      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to select data\n");
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);

      sqlite3_free(err_msg);
      sqlite3_close(db);

      return 1;
   } 

   sqlite3_close(db);

   window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
   list = gtk_tree_view_new();

   // CREATE 3 COLUMNS WITH TEXT CELL RENDERERS

   renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
   column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("ID",
          renderer, "text", LIST_ID, NULL);
   gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(list), column);

   renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
   column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("BRAND",
          renderer, "text", LIST_BRAND, NULL);
   gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(list), column);

   renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
   column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("PRICE",
          renderer, "text", LIST_PRICE, NULL);
   gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(list), column);


   // SET THE TREE VIEW MODEL 
   gtk_tree_view_set_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(list), GTK_TREE_MODEL(store));

   // TREEVIEW WILL KEEP A REFERENCE SO DECREASE REFCOUNT
   g_object_unref(store);

   // SETUP THE UI
   gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "List view");
   gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
   gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
   gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 270, 250);

   gtk_tree_view_set_headers_visible(GTK_TREE_VIEW(list), FALSE);

   vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);

   gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), list, TRUE, TRUE, 5);

   label = gtk_label_new("");
   gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), label, FALSE, FALSE, 5);

   gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

   g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

   gtk_widget_show_all(window);

   gtk_main();

   return 0;
}

int callback(void *model, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
   GtkTreeIter iter;

   for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {

      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");

   }

   printf("\n");

   // AFTER PRINTING TO CONSOLE FILL THE MODEL WITH THE DATA

   gtk_list_store_append (GTK_LIST_STORE(model), &iter);
   gtk_list_store_set (GTK_LIST_STORE(model), &iter, LIST_ID, argv[0],
         LIST_BRAND, argv[1],
         LIST_PRICE, argv[2],
         -1);

   return 0;
}
```

This example does not use GLADE because there's a bug when trying to setup cell renderers.  It's possible to create the treeview and columns but the cell renderers must be done programmatically.

The most important part is the sqlite3 callback which takes the GtkTreeModel/GtkListStore as first argument which then is filled with data, aka populated.

The model is then set as the treeview model and the treeview will show the query data.

Hope it helps.

PS: Compile with:

```
cc -o sqlview sqlview.c -lsqlite3 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much the example is very helpful . But i wonder why it is tricky to do that in C and gtk , i mean for C++ , Qt have a ready DataGrid which is very easy to manipulate, for C# also visual studio had a ready DataGrid . It seems like GTK is getting outdated ...

Comment: That's why I've asked about [libgda](https://developer.gnome.org/libgda/stable/) (has a GdaDataModel). Good luck